# MYSQL Slow query, how to optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

I have a big problem, I'm not very good with SQL... I have a database in mysql and when I do this query I have a response time around the 0.2s, so when i call it for a list of users (in a servlet) the response time goes around lots of seconds..

#### QUERY:

```
SELECT visible,nlikes,nomecognome,profile_img,users_face.id 
FROM users_face 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `likes_face`  
on (users_face.fb_id = likes_face.fb_id) 
WHERE  users_face.fb_id =? and users_face.token_valid=1
ORDER BY date DESC limit 1
```

Is there any way to optimize this code or any good resource to study the optimization of queries?

---

## CODE

```
   ArrayList<SocialMan> mans = new ArrayList<>();
    PreparedStatement ps;
    int nlikes, userid;
    String nomeCogn, prof;
    boolean visible;
    FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(token, Version.VERSION_2_6);
    com.restfb.Connection<User> myFriends;
    myFriends = facebookClient.fetchConnection("me/friends",User.class, Parameter.with("limit", 999));
    for (User u : myFriends.getData()) {
        nlikes = -1;
        userid = -1;
        nomeCogn = "ERROR";
        prof = "ERROR";
        visible = false;
        try {

                ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT visible,nlikes,nomecognome,profile_img,users_face.id FROM users_face LEFT OUTER JOIN `likes_face`  on (users_face.fb_id = likes_face.fb_id) WHERE  users_face.fb_id =? and users_face.token_valid=1 ORDER BY date DESC limit 1");

            ps.setString(1, "" + u.getId());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                nlikes = rs.getInt("nlikes");
                userid = rs.getInt("id");
                nomeCogn = rs.getString("nomecognome");
                prof = rs.getString("profile_img");
                visible = rs.getBoolean("visible");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FaceLikes.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //   System.out.println("NOMECOGNOME: "+nomeCogn);
        if (userid != -1 && visible) {                
            mans.add(new SocialMan(nomeCogn, userid, prof, nlikes));
        }
    }
    nlikes = -1;
    userid = -1;
    nomeCogn = "ERROR";
    prof = "ERROR";
```

## CREATE TABLE CODE

### USERS

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_face` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fb_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `fb_token` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `nomecognome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `data_iscrizione` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `profile_img` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `visible` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `TOKEN` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `locale` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `token_valid` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`fb_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `fb_id` (`fb_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=173 ;
```

### likes

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `likes_face` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `nlikes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fb_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1182636 ;
```

Comment: can you also give us your database structure?

Comment: how many rows is this query returning? are you sure you have to use left outer join?

Comment: _so when i call it for a list of users_ and `LIMIT 1`. how do you call your list??? show us your backend code outside mysql?

Comment: What does Your `EXPLAIN` look like?

Comment: I added the structure.
This query returns 1 row.
I have on the servlet a list of user ids getted from the request and i need to retrieve those datas for every single user.

Comment: show us your code. and you should change your query to `WHERE users.id IN (<<LIST OF VAL>>)` and remove your `LIMIT 1`. th issue is not even query, but the way you get data for the LIST

Comment: when we asked you for the structure. we meant `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement to see your indexes, but not only column names

Comment: ok sorry I thought to do it more understandable, now i add also the  create table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all I can come up with:

```
ALTER TABLE users_face ADD INDEX (fb_id, token_valid);

ALTER TABLE likes_face ADD INDEX (fb_id, nlikes, date);
```

You can't optimize the sorting, because the `date` column is in your non-primary table.

---

If you want to optimize further, the next thing to do is to move the `nlikes` and `date` columns into the users_face table, then make the index on that table over the following columns in this order: `(fb_id, token_valid, date, nlikes)`.

Then you can skip the join in your query, and the sort order will be the order of the index, so that will be optimized.

After that (or maybe *before* denormalizing), you should think about caching the data.

Comment: Thanks Bill, this reduced the time to 0.01 instead of 0.2! There's no thing that i can edit in the query (or maybe the structure) to improve the performance further?

Comment: If `nlikes` is being updated _frequently_, it is not wise to have it in any index.

Comment: @RickJames, with respect, I think that's an overgeneralization. It's true there is more overhead to updating an index versus not updating an index. But it can still be worth including a column in an index, depending on the queries you need to run. The difference is what you consider higher priority -- faster writes or faster reads. The covering index effect can give a huge improvement to some queries, enough to justify the overhead.

Comment: Hi Bill.  You have valid points.  For _this_ use case, I am assuming that "likes" are frequently updated and less frequently "selected".  (Maybe that assumption is wrong.)  In really busy "like" systems, the bumping of `likes` becomes the bottleneck.  Andrea probably does not _yet_ have a "really busy system", but I wanted to avoid that.  (As I point out in my answer, the are other things that need fixing before a 'covering' index bubbles to be the "most important".)

Comment: nlikes is never update, just stored every tot time in a new record automatic way, my priority is to have the faster reads as possible.

Answer (score 3):

("Read this entire answer before starting to take action.")

This does not make sense:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`fb_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `fb_id` (`fb_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
```

Tentatively, change to

```
PRIMARY KEY(fb_id),
INDEX(id)
```

on the assumption that you usually look up the record by fb_id.

If you say "list of users".  Do you mean that `WHERE fb_id IN ( ... )`?  Probably not since you have `LIMIT 1`.  Or do you mean that you call that `SELECT` repeatedly?

Gag!  `likes_face` has an id that you are not using, plus `fb_id` that you *are using* but is *not indexed*.  Use the *same* id for both tables: either get rid of `AUTO_INCREMENT` and change code logic for `likes_face`, or get rid of `id` and make `fb_id` the PK for both tables.

Are these tables 1:1?

Something is wrong.  Why does `likes_face have`AUTO_INCREMENT=1182636`, while there seem to be only 173 users?  If the tables are 1:1, are you using`REPLACE`?  You will run out of ids!

Restarting...

If the tables are 1:1:

- totally get rid of `id` on both tables and have `PRIMARY KEY(fb_id)` on both tables,
- make fb_id `CHARACTER SET ascii` if Facebook limits ids to ascii,
- no secondary indexes needed on either table.

If `likes_face` is a count of likes for each day:

- Get rid of `id` on both tables,
- make fb_id `CHARACTER SET ascii` if Facebook limits ids to ascii,
- Give `likes_face` `PRIMARY KEY(fb_id, date)`.
- no secondary indexes needed on either table.
- Use IODKU to do the increment/insert into the likes-per-day table.

If the tables are 1:many in some other way, I can't make sense of the schema.

Comment: I mean i call SELECT repeatedly, and it's the second case 1:many, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXPLAIN of statement of MYSQL. [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)

Someone suggested of creating indexes. Creating index is good option but avoid indexes if that column going to be modified frequently.

Comment: Re the second link...  Be cautious about apply Oracle advice to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks @RickJames. I have removed that link. However that was intended for the indexes not specifically to mysql or Oracle.